# Multiple Markers on Google Map: only last marker is shown

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am having a problem with displaying multiple markers on my map. The code starts by looping through an array, and then reverse geocoding the lat, lon values before displaying a marker and setting the content of the infoWindow to the returned address.

My codes are below.

```
for(var i=0; i < useNowArray.length; i++) {
        // plot useNow on map
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(useNowArray[i]['lat'], useNowArray[i]['lon']);
        console.log(useNowArray[i]['lat'] + useNowArray[i]['lon']);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                if (results[0]) 
                {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png',
                        title: results[0].formatted_address
                    });
                    content = results[0].formatted_address;
                    console.log(content);

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(content);
                            infowindow.open(map, this);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            } else {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        }); // end geocode function
    }  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

The issue is that only my last marker is shown.

What am i missing? :(

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your marker variable is global, geocoding is asynchronous.  The loop executes, firing off useNowArray.length requests, each one updates the global marker with the resulting position.  When the loop is done, the marker is left at the last location in the loop.  Similar questions with solutions to the issue:

- [Google Maps API v3 - fitBounds after multiple geocoder requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336405/google-maps-api-v3-fitbounds-after-multiple-geocoder-requests)
- [Problem with multiple markers (Google Maps API v3 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266377/problem-with-multiple-markers-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: In fact he is using this code: http://www.svennerberg.com/2012/03/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-from-json/ but it's extremly poor example, i.e. It cannot work for the reason you mentioned. I also wonder how this person can write a book and find a publisher.

Comment: The demo on that [page](http://www.svennerberg.com/2012/03/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-from-json/) does not have this problem and doesn't use the geocoder.

Comment: thanks for the response!

only changing my marker variable to local does not solve the problem right? i did that and also tried comparing address_count and my array length like in the fitBounds example but it didnt work for me either. 

help T_T

Comment: okay its solved now. setting the marker's position to the latlng variable was the problem since it would have been overwritten by the next latlng values by the time the callback function runs. i fixed it by setting position: results[0].geometry.location instead.

finally works now. thanks guys!